# Change position of word

Tags: awk, sed

I have file with multiples lines as given below with header for each species starting with '>'

```
>gi|398852808|ref|NZ_AKJD01000108.1| Pseudomonas sp. GM80 PMI37_contig126.126, whole genome shotgun sequence
CCGCAGGCTGCGATCTTTTGATGTTGTTTTTTTAAGATCAAGATCAAAAGATCGCAGCCTTCGGCAGCTCCTACAGGTGG
TCGTGGGTTTAAGCCGCTCAATCCAGTAAACTGCGGCACGTTTTTCTCTAAGTAGTGTTTTCCCCATGCAAATTGCTCTG
GCGCCCATGGAGGGGTTGGTCGACGACATCCTCCGCGACGTGCTGACCCGCGTTGGCGGCATCGATTGGTGCGTGACTGA
ATTCATTCGGGTCAACGATCAGTTGCTCACCCCGGCTTACTTCCACAAGTTCGGCCCCGAGCTGCTCAACGGTGCCCGCA
CGGCGTCCGGCGTGCCATTGCGTGTGCAATTGCTCGGTTCCGACCCGGTGTGCCTGGCGGAAAACGCTGCACTGGCCTGC
```

I would like to find the header and change it to

```
>NZ_AKJD01000108.1|kraken:taxid|398852808 Pseudomonas sp. A3(2016), complete genome
CGCGATGGTCGTTAACGAAAACGCATGCTTACTGGCTAAACGCGGCGCTCTTGACTCCAT
CGCGAGCAAGCTCGCTCCTACAGAAGAAAGCGGCGCTCTAGTGCGCCTCATCCCAGTTAT
TGCCTACCCCCACCTCGACCAGCAGCGGCACATCCAGTTGCGCGGCCCCGCTCATGTGCA
```

Without changing the structure of the file.

I tried this

```
awk -v repl=">kraken:taxid|$ID|" '{ gsub(/^>/,repl,$0); print $0}' $FILE
```

I am able to move words but not able to remove or get the desired result. Also is there a faster way to do it the size of file is 230 Gb

Comment: what is difference between original text and changed text? explain it

Comment: well for now all that matters is the position of the string                                                       >gi|abc|xxx|NZxxx|bacterial_species name                                                   to                                                                                                                      >NZ_xxx|kraken:id|abc bacterial_species name

Comment: can we assume that the header field (and only header fields) starts with a ">" ? And that fields are delimited by "|"? And that you want to move field 4 to field 1; insert text a new field "kraken:taxid", combine field 2 with 5; and remove fields 1 and 3?

Comment: yes spot on @jeff

Comment: That'd be a great edit to make, then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one way would be to make use of the `|` characters as field separators e.g.

```
awk -v repl="kraken:taxid" 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=FS} /^>/ {$1=">"$4;$3=$2$5;$2=repl;NF-=2}1'
```

Testing with your data as `file`:

```
$ awk -v repl="kraken:taxid" 'BEGIN{FS="|";OFS=FS} /^>/ {$1=">"$4;$3=$2$5;$2=repl;NF-=2}1' file
>NZ_AKJD01000108.1|kraken:taxid|398852808 Pseudomonas sp. GM80 PMI37_contig126.126, whole genome shotgun sequence
CCGCAGGCTGCGATCTTTTGATGTTGTTTTTTTAAGATCAAGATCAAAAGATCGCAGCCTTCGGCAGCTCCTACAGGTGG
TCGTGGGTTTAAGCCGCTCAATCCAGTAAACTGCGGCACGTTTTTCTCTAAGTAGTGTTTTCCCCATGCAAATTGCTCTG
GCGCCCATGGAGGGGTTGGTCGACGACATCCTCCGCGACGTGCTGACCCGCGTTGGCGGCATCGATTGGTGCGTGACTGA
ATTCATTCGGGTCAACGATCAGTTGCTCACCCCGGCTTACTTCCACAAGTTCGGCCCCGAGCTGCTCAACGGTGCCCGCA
CGGCGTCCGGCGTGCCATTGCGTGTGCAATTGCTCGGTTCCGACCCGGTGTGCCTGGCGGAAAACGCTGCACTGGCCTGC
```

---

You may find that perl is faster especially for large files; a (probably over-literal) translation would be

```
perl -F'\|' -ane 'print /^>/ ? join "|", ">".$F[3], "kraken:taxid", $F[1].$F[4] : $_' file
```

but there is likely a more idiomatic way of doing it.

Comment: thanks..for another pipeline I would just need                                                 >NZ_AKJD01000108.1 Pseudomonas sp. GM80 PMI37_contig126.126, whole genome shotgun sequence                                                                    with a tab in between so do i remove the reply and keep $3=.....?

Comment: @sidbio sorry I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: @ steeldriver i am also trying to use this file for a different pipe line where my output header would be just  >NZ_AKJD01000108.1'\t'Bacterial_speciesname , so do i not include repl=kraken:id  in your code and also remove $2=repl.

Comment: FYI if these are fasta files then you might want to look at some of the dedicated tools such as [BioPerl](http://bioperl.org/howtos/SeqIO_HOWTO.html)